# Sending mail on PHP using LAMP

Tags: php, email, smtp, lamp

I have been trying for awhile now to send mail using PHP, and I can't seem to get it to work.

I looked at the tutorials, and they make it seem simple enough. Yet, it seems to actually require more work than what is mentioned. Through research (to make this short), it seems that instead of the "From: " header actually having the address I give to it, it seems that... sendmail replaces it or something with daemon@ubuntu? Ok, even if I don't include a header I still get spam from my gmail account from the daemon@ubuntu thing (I am running ubuntu on a vm, and sending mail to my gmail account). I guess this could explain why I incessantly get errors when I try to send mail saying how there is an error in the "MAIL FROM command".

So before I get myself involved with messing around with sendmail, is this the (likely)culprit of the daemon@ubuntu nonsense? The tutorials make mention of having things like sendmail, but they really don't go into any details of what to do with them. I did make sure that sendmail is being used in my php configuration file.

I have heard of alternative mail servers like PHPmail or something like that. I really don't want to get involved in installing and configuring more software unless I really have to. So unless you guys really think sendmail isn't worth it, I would prefer advice on sendmail if it is the problem.

Thank you for your time.

edit: I am using the PHP mail() function on an Ubuntu vm by VMware Player.

So someone wanted to see my code. I somewhat wanted to avoid this simply because I tried many different possibilities. I will just include what I have in my file right now:

```
<?php
                    $myEmail    = "####@gmail.com";
                    $fromAddr   = $_POST['sender-email'];

                    $headers    = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                    $headers   .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                    $headers   .= "From: $fromAddr\r\n";
                    $headers   .= "'X-Mailer: PHP/'" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
                    $message    = $_POST['message'];

                    $status     = mail($myEmail, $_POST['subj'], $message);

                    if($status) {
                        echo "Your message has been sent, " .$fromAddr. "!";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "An error occurred while trying to send the mail.";
                    }
                ?>
```

The MIME type thing, and Content-type thing I added later on. I have tried this without them. I have also tried sending mail without using any headers at all, and still apparently get the daemon@ubuntu thing. Also, I edited out my e-mail address to post the code on here. Ok I guess I should add this too: I am getting the data from an HTML form from another page. On submit, I come to this php page where it grabs that data and then sends the email (this isn't for anything professional, I am just doing this to learn more about web stuff).

Comment: a) what solution do you use for sending emails? You don't say... Is it the builtin solution or some smtp client class? b) you have to distinguish between headers inside an email (this is what you _see_ in the email) and the addresses the email acutally gets send from and to (which is what _happens_).

Comment: ah sorry. I am using the mail() function.

Comment: Ok, then what are your settings for that inside your `php.ini` configuration file?

Comment: just what they had in the file.
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t

Comment: Ok, so I suggest two things: 1) post an example message as you generat it inside php (I want to see the exact headers contents) and try using `sendmail -t` from command line (handing it the above message).

Comment: ok, I will include it in the edit

Comment: So I actually don't know much about sendmail. I just know about it. From your and the other guy's post, it seems that this might be a mail server issue. I am going off for now to sleep, will be back later. I just wasn't sure if maybe there was some kind of concept I was missing about sending mail, but it seems like this might be the case (and not my code). I actually only just set up my first LAMP stack a couple days ago, so I am still getting used to the web stuff.

Answer (score 2):

[Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) is a very easy to use and install email server, in my experience. You need an email server installed and configured before you're able to send email on your localhost.